# Show graph on display and save it to file simultaneously in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

How can I save graph in to file and also print it to display? I've tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -p

date=system("date +%F_%T | sed 's/:/-/g'")

set term png
set output date.".png"

set term x11
set out

plot sin(x)
```

PS: Is there a possibility to save the graph which is displayed in gnuplot window? I've noticed that there is copy to clipboard button but no save.

Comment: Since version 5 gnuplot has a save button for the `qt` and the `wxt` terminal.

Comment: Hello Christoph, is there a way of how to make it work for gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 0?

Comment: Here we are in July 2017 using version 5.0 patchlevel 3, and the date thing solved a huge problem for me.  I didn't know about date +%F (I just need the date since I only do this at midnight after the day's data is collected), and about concatenating in gnuplot to make the filename.  This whole thing for me is automated using mcron to time things down to the second.  Excellent.  I tip my hat to you.  Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to send a plot both to a file and to an interactive terminal like `x11` or `wxt` you have the `replot` after you changed the terminal

```
set terminal png
set output 'file.png'

plot sin(x)

set terminal x11
set output
replot
```

If you don't want to set the `x11` terminal explicitely, but rather use the default terminal, whatever it is, you can use the special terminals `push` and `pop` so save and restore a terminal:

```
set terminal push
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'file.png'
plot sin(x)
set terminal pop
set output
replot
```

To make this more transparent and save any image after you plotted it to an interactive terminal you could define a gnuplot script `export.gp` which you can then `call` and give the output file name as parameter.

The `export.gp` script is

```
set terminal push
set terminal pngcairo
set output '$0'

replot
set output
set terminal pop
```

which you can then use as

```
plot sin(x)
call 'export.gp' 'test.png'
```

Note, however, that the exported file and the plot shown in the interactive window will be different, but if you use `wxt` as interactive and `pngcairo` or `pdfcairo` as output terminals, the chances are quite high, that displayed and exported images are very similar.

With gnuplot 5.0 the `qt` and `wxt` terminals offer an "Export" button to save exactly the image shown in the window as svg, pdf or png files. Unfortunately, this functionality cannot yet be invoked from a script, i.e. there is no `export` command.

Comment: Thank you for the info about push and pop.  I didn't know about that.  I use reread for my visible plots a lot.  But this is a whole new way to do it.  However, mine continually reread.  I didn't know about replot.  Will have to look into that because I might not want it to do it continually like reread does.

Comment: Needs to be mentioned: replotting works fine with a single plot, however, does not work if you have a `multiplot`, because `replot` will only replot the last plot of a multiplot environment.

Comment: The image is saved as '$0' when using export .gp script

Comment: @tejassbetty `$0` was the old, deprecated syntax. Since version 5 you should use `set output ARG0`

Answer (score 1):

A good answer was also given in [gnuplot - How can I save a graphics file of a plot that is the same as I designed it in xterminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44468524/11769765).
For `x11` terminal one can use

```
system("xwd -id ".GPVAL_TERM_WINDOWID." | convert xwd:- screenshot.png")
```

It can be also wrapped into a short cut

```
bind "Ctrl-c" 'system("xwd -id ".GPVAL_TERM_WINDOWID." | convert xwd:- png:- | xclip -sel clip -t image/png")'
```

So you plot the image

```
set term x11
plot sin(x)/x
```

and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> in the plot window. Just here, I pasted the image with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>:

[image]

Unfortunately, it does not work for `qt` or `wxt` (`GPVAL_TERM_WINDOWID` is associated to `x11`). They have clipboard buttons, but snapshots are not scriptable.

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding on [Chistofs comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30334657/7952027)
I like to keep the save commands and decide the file name at the end.
So, modifying the answer gave me this

```sh
plot sin(x)
set terminal push
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'test.png'

replot
set output
set terminal pop
```