# gnuplot - X axis is a time value - X11 plot is fine. How to make .png look similar

Tags: fonts, gnuplot

This is datalogger output of sun intensity.

Here is an excerpt of what the data looks like:

```
2017-09-24  12:44:48    1440
2017-09-24  12:45:49    1434
2017-09-24  12:46:50    1445
2017-09-24  12:47:51    1446
2017-09-24  12:48:52    1434
2017-09-24  12:49:53    1431
```

This plot is displayed in an xterm and looks perfect:

[image]

Generated by this program:

```
set title "OUTSIDE Light Intensity"
set xlabel "Time"
set ylabel "LUX"
set yrange [0:*]
set grid
unset mouse
unset log
set key top left
set timestamp
set xdata time
set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'
set xtics format '%H:%M'
set terminal x11
set datafile missing "0.00"
plot 1750 lw 1 lc rgb 'black' t "South", \
     "today.dat" using 2:($3*1.5) with lines lw 1 lc rgb 'red' t "Lux"
pause 30
reread
```

as per

[How can you watch gnuplot realtime data plots as a live graph, with automatic updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44470965/how-can-you-watch-gnuplot-realtime-data-plots-as-a-live-graph-with-automatic-up)

So far, so good.

---

The gnuplot program that runs in cron generates the .png file equivalent.  It is the same except for the terminal setting and specification of an output file:

```
set output "plux.png"
set terminal pngcairo
plot 1750 lw 2 lc rgb 'black' t "South", \
     "today.dat" using 2:($3*1.5) with lines lw 2 lc rgb 'red' t "Lux"
```

and the output looks like this:

[image]

**So my question is:   How can I control the .png plot so it looks the same as in the x11 terminal?**

Seems to have something to do with the fonts.

This article talks to it:

[gnuplot documentation: fonts](http://www.bersch.net/gnuplot-doc/fonts.html)

Excerpt:

> Gnuplot does not provide any fonts of its own. It relies on external font handling, the details of which unfortunately vary from one terminal type to another.

Comment: Use `wxt` and `pngcairo`, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30334657/260421

Comment: That's pretty cool.  But that would presuppose that I always have the live graphs running.  I opted to have cron generate the png files at intervals all through the day until Midnight when the eod (end of day) python scripts run to archive everything collected from the various Rpi/Nano sensors all over the place, naming them by date.  That way I can go on camping trips and it will still operate itself unattended, saving it all to disk to guard against SD card or flash drive failure (of which there have been a few).  So the png generation programs are separate from the live plot programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer is much easier when the terminal is set to `png` like so:

```
set term png font "arial,11"
```

When this is done, the output file looks like this:

[image]

That's great.

---

But it begs the question of what font is used in the X11 terminal since it is not mentioned in the fonts page provided in the OP.

So here we go:   [gnuplot:  X11_fonts](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node443.html)

Excerpt:

> Upon initial startup, the default font is taken from the X11 resources
>   as set in the system or user .Xdefaults file or on the command line.
>
> Example: 
>        gnuplot*font: lucidasans-bold-12
>
> A new default font may be specified to the x11 driver from inside gnuplot using
>
> ```
> `set term x11 font "<fontspec>"`
> ```
>
> The driver first queries the X-server for a font of the exact name
>   given.

---

---

In the end, the png terminal with arial font is just fine for these png files.

They are used in montages for each day that include a whole pageful of plotted variables for the solar power station.

Having them similar to each other is much more important to this project than to force them to look the same as they do on-screen.